# validation in oracle java adf

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-adf

1.9.0 i what to do this key-next trigger validation in java

i what something like this but in java adf

```
protected PreparedStatement createStatementADF(String query)
{
    PreparedStatement statement=null;
    try {

              /*create transaction for current statemtnt*/
              DBTransaction dbTransaction = (DBTransaction) this.getTransaction();
              statement= dbTransaction.createPreparedStatement(query, 0);
    } catch (SQLException e)
    {
              throw new JboException(e);
    }
    return statement;

}
/*Executes single query*/
protected ResultSet executeQueryADF (String query, Object[] bindVars)
{
          PreparedStatement statement=null;
          ResultSet ret=null;
          try {

              /*create transaction for current statemtnt and resuse it*/
              statement=createStatementADF(query);

              if ((bindVars != null)&&(statement!=null)) {
                  // 2. Loop over values for the bind variables passed in, if any
                  for (int z = 0; z < bindVars.length; z++) {
                      // 3. Set the value of each bind variable in the statement
                      statement.setObject(z + 1, bindVars[z]);
                  }
              }
              // 4. Execute the statement
              ret=statement.executeQuery();
          } catch (SQLException e) {
              throw new JboException(e);
          } finally {
              if (statement != null) {
                  try {
                      // 5. Close the statement
                      statement.close();
                  } catch (SQLException e) {
                  }
              }
          }
          return ret;
}
public void getUsrStatus()
{
        ResultSet rs = null;
        Object[] bindVars = new Object[]{"TestUser"};

        try {
            rs = executeQueryADF("SELECT account_status  FROM  dba_users WHERE  username = ?", bindVars );
            while(rs.next())
            {
                //..... process data
            }
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
        }

    }
```

where i can use valueChangeListener,i what to validate the password and call the procedure to validate the password,i have to validate based on the enterd useid

```
public void labelListener(ValueChangeEvent valueChangeEvent)
  { UIComponent c = valueChangeEvent.getComponent();

    //This step actually invokes Update Model phase for this 
    //component
    c.processUpdates(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());

    //Jump to the Render Response phase in order to avoid 
    //the validation
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().renderResponse();
  }
```

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: yes how can i do this validation in adf

Comment: You want to execute the PL/SQL or you want to convert the PL/SQL to Java?

Comment: i what to convert the pl/sql to java adf

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a View Object (VO) which uses following query:

   ```
   SELECT account_status
         FROM   dba_users
         WHERE  username = :p_username
   ```

   Where p_username is a bind variable and add the VO to your Application Module (AM)
2. In your AM you will need to create a new method which gets the VO,
   set the bind variable and execute the VO. Here you do the validations by checking the number of rows and see if the status etc is correct.

Depending on your use case you should expose the method in your AM (which probably returns a boolean or string). Add that method to your bindings and execute it when the user does some action (click a button). With the result of your method you could do some navigation or show an error. (Throwing an exception could also be a option).

**Edit:**
You can move your PL/SQL into a function/procedure and execute it from your AM. Very nice ex: http://www.baigzeeshan.com/2010/05/calling-plsql-procedure-and-function-in.html

Comment: and when will I call the procedure and do this

Comment: IF :work.accnt_stat = 'OPEN' then
          validate_pswd('T',
                    'dbusername',
                    null,
                    null,
                    passwd,
                    wrk_err_ind,
                    wrk_err_msg);
      IF nvl(wrk_err_,'N') = 'Y' THEN
         message(wrk_msg);
         raise form_trigger_failure;
      END IF;